# Are there any Bitcoin alt-coin creation tutorials above version 0.15.0?

Tags: bitcoin-core, altcoin, genesis-block

There are many `How to make an alt-coin` tutorials out there, but all the ones I have seen are from 2015 or earlier (most are around 2013-2014). Bitcoin has changed **dramatically** since then, and I am pulling my hair out trying to follow tutorials that are completely outdated.

Are there any tutorials on creating Altcoins using Bitcoin for version 0.15.0 or higher?

Comment: If you need a tutorial to create an altcoin, you probably shouldn't be making an altcoin I'm afraid :) Unless you're doing it for learning purposes, but I'd then suggest just sticking with an older version of bitcoin

Comment: There doesn't look to be any tutorials, at least from what I can find. You can always use the older tutorials and when you run into issues, post another question on here. Then at the end you can write up your experience and teach other people how to create an alt-coin :)